# How to count subdocuments recursively

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have documents in my db that look like this:

```
{
  "id": "1"
  "entityType": "node"
  "childNodes": [
   {
     "id": "2"
     "entityType": "node"
     "childNodes": [
          ...
     ]
   }
  ]
}
```

As a large tree structure.

I'd like to count the total number of documents and subdocuments in my collection that are of entityType = "Node".

My attempt is to get the data one level at a time manually:

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(c.id) FROM c where CONTAINS(c.id, 'a|') and c.entityType = 'node'
SELECT VALUE COUNT(l.id) FROM c JOIN l in c.childNodes where CONTAINS(c.id, 'a|') and c.entityType = 'node'
SELECT VALUE COUNT(l2.id) FROM c JOIN l in c.childNodes JOIN l2 in l.childNodes where CONTAINS(c.id, 'a|') and c.entityType = 'node'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's hard to find a smooth(direct) way to implement your needs.Surely,the manual way you mentioned in your question works.However,if you have too many layers of JSON nesting, or it's random,your way maybe inappropriate.

I would suggest you loop the result recursively to get the count of objects which contains `"entityType": "node"`.For example, in the cosmos db stored procedure:

```
function sample(prefix) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT c.childNodes FROM c where c.entityType = "node"',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var count = {count:1};
            loopChildNodes(feed,count);
            response.setBody(count);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');

    function loopChildNodes(array,count){
        for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            console.log(count)
            if(array[i].entityType == "node"){
                count.count++;
            }
            if(array[i].childNodes!=null)
                loopChildNodes(array[i].childNodes,count)
        }
    }
}
```

My test data:

[image]

Output:

[image]